# How to change the pagination of related entities displayed on a taxonomy term page?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, theming, 7, paging

On a default taxonomy term page, related contents are automatically paginated by 10.

Let's say those related contents are always nodes and we always display the default teaser view mode.

How can I change the number of *node teaser by page* **without using a module or a view?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The taxonomy module uses the `default_nodes_main` variable to decide how many to show per page (this happens around line 55 of taxonomy.pages.inc in case you're interested).

Usually you would implement a custom module and provide a form to override that variable for your users. But you don't *have* to do that, if you just want to set the variable once and be done with it use one of the following methods instead:

1. Use Drush (`drush vset default_nodes_main 20`)
2. Add a PHP snippet somewhere that will be run in your site (you only need to do it once)

   ```
   variable_set('default_nodes_main', 20);
   ```
3. Use the Devel variable editor